# ASP.NET MVC5 - Adding items to model virtual list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a model called club and each club has a virtual list property for the members of that club. I am lost as to how to add more members to that list and then save it to my database.

```
public class Club
    {
        [Key]
        public int ClubID { get; set; }

        public string ClubName { get; set; }

        public string ClubDescription { get; set; }


        //List of Members that are members of this Club
        public virtual List<ClubMember> ClubMembers { get; set; }

    }//end Club
```

This is the ClubMember model:

```
public class ClubMember
{
    [Key]
    public int MemberId { get; set; }

    //First Name
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string MemberFName { get; set; }

    //Last Name
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must enter a Last Name")]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string MemberLName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Member Name")]
    public string MemberName { get; set; }

    public string MemberEmail { get; set; }

    //Foreign Key for Club
    public int ClubID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ClubID")]
    public virtual Club Club { get; set; }
}
```

I am using a wrapper model to get a list of the selected ids for the members that the user wishes to add but I'm not sure if this is needed:

```
public class NewMemberList //Class used when adding new members to the members list of a club
    {
        public List<ClubMember> NewMembers { get; set; }
        public List<int> SelectedIDs { get; set; }
    }
```

This is what I currently have in my view for adding a member, it just displays a drop-down list with a list of members and a submit button

```
@model ultimateorganiser.Models.NewMemberList

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add Members";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm(@Model.SelectedIDs))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedIDs, new MultiSelectList(Model.NewMembers, "UserId", "UserFName", Model.SelectedIDs))

    <input type="submit" value="save" />   
}
```

This is the controller method I have. It is not finished as I do not know how to handle the post part so that it gets the list of selected ids and adds all of the data for that member to the members list in the club:

```
 [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult AddMembers(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            Club club = db.Clubs.Find(id);

            if (club == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            List<ClubMember> CurrentMembers = club.ClubMembers;

            List<ClubMember> MembersList = new List<ClubMember>();
            MembersList = db.ClubMembers.ToList();

            ViewBag.CurrentMembersList = CurrentMembers;
            return View(new NewMemberList() { NewMembers = MembersList });
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult AddMembers([Bind(Include = "SelectedIDs")] Club club)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //Get selected members and add them to Members list for the club
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(club);      

     }
```

If you have questions or would like to see more of my code just ask.

Comment: Can a member be created without associating with a Club ? Currently the ClubId in Member class is not null, That means you must have a club associated with it. It your requirement to change the connection to another club ?

Comment: Sorry that is a mistake that Ii have overlooked but yes a member can exist without being associated to a club

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view model should store the ClubId as well since you are adding the new members to a specific Club.

```
public class AddMembersToClub
{
  public string Name { set;get;}
  public int ClubId { set;get;}
  public List<SelectListItem> Members { set;get;}
  public int[] SelectedMembers { set;get;}
}
```

And in your GET action,

```
public ActionResult AddMembers(int id)
{
    var club = db.Clubs.Find(id);
    if (club == null)
    {
       return HttpNotFound();
    }
  var vm = new AddMembersToClub { ClubId=id , Name = club.ClubName };
  //Here I am getting all the members, If you want a subset, update the LINQ query
  vm.Members = db.ClubMembers
              .Select(x=> new SelectListItem { Value = x.MemberId.ToString(),
                                               Text=x.MemberFName }).ToList();
  return View(vm);
}
```

and in your view, which is strongly typed to our `AddMembersToClub` view model. You need to keep the `ClubId` in a hidden form field as we need that in the HttpPost action.

```
@model AddMembersToClub
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
   <p>Adding members to @Model.Name</p>

   @Html.HiddenFor(s=>s.ClubId)
   @Html.ListBoxFor(s => s.SelectedMembers, Model.Members)

   <input type="submit" />
}
```

And in your HttpPost action, Read the SelectedMembers property which is an int array storing the Id's of selected members and using the Id, get the Member entity and udpate the `ClubId` property.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddMembers(AddMembersToClub model)
{
   foreach(var item in model.SelectedMembers)
   {
     var member = db.ClubMembers.FirstOrDefault(s=>s.MemberId==item);
     if(member!=null)
     {
        member.ClubId = model.ClubId;
     }
     db.SaveChanges();
   }
   return ReidrectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Any thought as to why I get this error when I run that code "NotSupportedException was unhandled by user code". I get this error on these lines - `var vm = new AddMembersToClub { ClubId=id , Name = club.Name };
  //Here I am getting all the members, If you want a subset, update the LINQ query
  vm.Members = db.ClubMembers
              .Select(x=> new SelectListItem { Value = x.MemberId.ToString(),
                                               Text=x.MemberFName }).ToList();` on the GET Action

Comment: Change `Name` to `ClubName` or whatever your property is